# Vue js how to animate component display from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuejs2

I have four components when you hover the mouse over the picture, a certain component is displayed, the problem is that my components are displayed ugly without animation, I want to do so that when I hover over the picture, my components are displayed in an animated way from top to bottom.

As you can see, I have four pictures, for example, when you hover over the first picture, the first component is displayed when you hover over the second, the second component, and so on.

```
    <div class="EnjoyGirlsList">

      <div @mouseover="mouseOver1" @mouseout="mouseout" class="EnjoyCard">
        <div>
          <img src="~@/assets/Images/HomePage/EnjoyGirlsList/Rectangle-1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
          <div style="background: #74C8C5" class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
            <h3>Teens</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div @mouseover="mouseOver2" @mouseout="mouseout" class="EnjoyCard">
        <div>
          <img src="~@/assets/Images/HomePage/EnjoyGirlsList/Rectangle-2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
          <div style="background: #76ED00" class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
            <h3>Minxes</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div @mouseover="mouseOver3" @mouseout="mouseout" class="EnjoyCard">
        <div>
          <img src="~@/assets/Images/HomePage/EnjoyGirlsList/Rectangle-3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
          <div style="background: #FFE600" class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
            <h3>MILFS</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div @mouseover="mouseOver4" @mouseout="mouseout" class="EnjoyCard">
        <div>
          <img src="~@/assets/Images/HomePage/EnjoyGirlsList/Rectangle-4.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
          <div style="background: #CC003D" class="EnjoyCardChildContainer">
            <h3>COURGARS</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="EnjoyGirlsHoverEffect">
    <EnjoyBlue v-show="img1"/>
    <EnjoyGreen v-show="img2"/>
    <EnjoyYellow v-show="img3" />
    <EnjoyRed v-show="img4" />
  </div>

export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  components: {EnjoyRed, EnjoyYellow, EnjoyGreen, EnjoyBlue, Navbar, GirlsSectionList, FeaturedShows,},
  data() {
    return {
      img1: false,
      img2: false,
      img3: false,
      img4: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mouseOver1: function(){
      this.img1 = true
    },
    mouseOver2: function(){
      this.img2 = true
    },
    mouseOver3: function(){
      this.img3 = true
    },
    mouseOver4: function(){
      this.img4 = true
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      this.img1 = false;
      this.img2 = false;
      this.img3 = false;
      this.img4 = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide an example on codepen or jsfiddle so that we can see and help you... for now, we can see only code :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <slide-y-up-transition>
    <RedExperience v-show="img1"  />
    </slide-y-up-transition>
    <slide-y-up-transition>
      <OrangeExperience v-show="img2" />
    </slide-y-up-transition>
    <slide-y-up-transition>
      <GreenExperience v-show="img4" />
    </slide-y-up-transition>
    <slide-y-up-transition>
      <BlueExperience v-show="img3" />
    </slide-y-up-transition>
  </div>

import {SlideYUpTransition} from 'vue2-transitions'
  components: {SlideYUpTransition},
```